# Как создать платное приложение?

Tags: qml, защита, платежи, взлом

Разрабатываю приложение, которое планирую продавать. Какими методами его можно защитить от пиратства? Каким образом следует генерировать и проверять серийные ключи? Приложение будет использовать QML, стоит ли защищать эти файлы от редактирования?

Comment: А смысл? Если будет популярное всё равно ломанут, а если нет то на постановку защиты потратите больше чем заработаете :-)

Но если у приложение должен быть доступ к интернету - лучше держать сервер который будет проверять лицензии. А ещё лучше отдавать код если ключ верный.

Answer (score 3):

Очень важно на чем вы пишете, потому что транслируемые языки (C#, Java) компилируя промежуточный код попутно сохраняют различную мета-информацию, используя которую, современные декомпиляторы способны практически в первозданном виде восстанавливать исходный код (особенно это касается C#). Поэтому все же лучше использовать компилируемые языки (C, C++) если не для всего приложения, то хотя бы для важных библиотек или частей программы. Хотя особенно это не поможет, но гарантирует что не каждый школьник будет ломать программу как показано на видео в ютубе.
Очень важно для какой системы, потому что у каждой есть свои особенности и возможности которые вы должны будете использовать для защиты, а злоумышленник использует для взлома.
Пользуйтесь всевозможными обфускаторами, используйте в местах критических к безопасности рефлексию (если язык поддерживает, это значительно улучшает результаты обфускации), для строк используйте Base64, никогда не храните никакие ключи внутри программы.
НО если кому-то это действительно очень понадобится, то обязательно сломают.
Чад верно сказал, опрашивать сервер на "поломатость" твой программы - лучший вариант, а если еще подключение к интернету ей необходимо во время работы, то получать от сервера временный одноразовый ключ.

Comment: С++, интерфейс на QML